# How do I merge vertices into another polygon?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to Blender and I'm trying to make a low-poly wolf, but the problem I'm having is when I have to create a new polygon in between some vertices. I can't, for the love of me, figure this out. I tried to press ALT+M=>At Center, but that just jumbles up the vertices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a new face (polygon), select the vertices or edges with <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right click, then press <kbd>F</kbd>.

[image: make face polygon]

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways, it depends on what you need to do:

1. If you need a new face, select the relevant edges while in (Edit Mode)
   Edge Select and press F.
2. If you need more geometry from within a face, select Face Select (Edit Mode), right click on the relevant face then press W. This will bring up a menu, select subdivide, On the left side of the screen you will see that you can choose the number of cuts you need for your shape. Once you are done modelling, you can always get rid of the extra lines by pressing X, then dissolve (edges, faces or vertices).
3. Something a little bit trickier, is the use of the knife when you do have a face but you want to make irregular changes within it. Press K, select your starting point and left click. Move to the second point and left click again. When you are done with your cutting, press the bar space.